# Calculate total sum of dynamic inputs with auto updating the sum when a dynamic row is deleted or added

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

[When the page loads, the sum should be printed in the output inputs below the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnuP5.png)

[Also, new numbers should be added to the total automatically when dynamically adding and deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSDv6.png)
I am trying to get the total sum of the numbers inside the two specified  inputs in the following code, first: I want to get the sum before adding any new dynamic row, second: I want the sum to be updated automatically if a new dynamic row is added or a dynamic row is deleted, any help Will you be appreciated and praised.
display sum total of quantity in the `(input class =sum_of_quantity)` and sum total of amount in the `(input class =sum_of_amount)`

```
<table id="dynamicAddRemove">
        <tr>
          <th class="wd-15p fontColor">Quantity</th>
          <th class="wd-15p fontColor">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity"/></td>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity"/></td>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]"class="form-control amount"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity"/></td>
          <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" /></td>
          <td class="td2"><button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_quantity" readonly>
            <input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_amount" readonly >
```

```
    $("#add-btn").click(function() {
$("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td class="td"><input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"/></td>
 <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount" class="form-control amount"/></td>
 <td class="td2"><button type="button" value="1000" name="add" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var total =0;
        $('.quantity').each(function() {
          total += parseFloat($(this).val());
          $('.one').val(total);
        });
        var sum =$('.one').val();
        $(".quantity").on("change keyup", function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
      $('.one').val(sum).toFixed(2);
    });
      });
```

Comment: Please note you can't have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I deleted the ID and just relied on the class

Comment: please explain little detail

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM First, look at the code I just modified for clarity.
and What is required ? When this page is loaded, the sum of the numbers inside the inputs that carry the classes `(class="form-control quantity , class="form-control amount)` should be displayed automatically, and the total sum is displayed in the specified  inputs by the following classes: `(input class =sum_of_quantity) ( input class =sum_of_amount)` , and when you press the Add More button, a new row will be added, and when writing any number in any entry, it must be automatically added to the sum total

Comment: If you don't want to have to add event handlers to dynamically generated fields explicitly all the time, then go read up on the keyword _event delegation_.

Comment: What is `i`? I do not see it declared.

Comment: @76484 Sorry, error in the code

Comment: @76484 `$(document).ready(function() {
  var total =0;
    $('.quantity').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
      $('.one').val(total);
    });
    var sum =$('.one').val();
    $(".quantity").on("change keyup", function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
  $('.one').val(sum).toFixed(2);
});
  });`  This code automatically gets the sum of the inputs when the page is loaded, but does not work when the value of any inputs is changed

Comment: @sallyntod: If you already have the code then it seems all that you need to do is to wrap it in a function and call that function when the inputs emit the events. You _will_ need to use event delegation. See the update to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a function that will loop through each `amount[]` input, get the value as a `Number` and then sum all of those values. It would do the exact same thing for the `quantity[]` inputs.

We can use jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to map each row to an object containing its `amount` and `quantity` and then use JavaScript's [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to turn the mapped values into a total amount and quantity - making sure to multiply each `amount` by the `quantity` in its corresponding row.

The resultant function would look like:

```
const updateTotals = () => {
  const amountsAndQuantities = $('#dynamicAddRemove tbody tr').map(function () {
    const quantity = Number($(this).find('input[name="quantity[]"], input[name="quantity"]').val()) || 0;
    const amount = Number($(this).find('input[name="amount[]"], input[name="amount"]').val()) || 0;
    
    return {
      amount,
      quantity
    };
  }).get();

  const totals = amountsAndQuantities.reduce((acc, amountAndQuantity) => {
    return {
      amount: acc.amount + amountAndQuantity.quantity * amountAndQuantity.amount,
      quantity: acc.quantity + amountAndQuantity.quantity
    };
  }, { amount: 0, quantity: 0 });
  
  $('.sum_of_quantity').val(totals.quantity);
  $('.sum_of_amount').val(totals.amount.toFixed(2));
};
```

**Update**

I have updated the code above so that the `amount` sum is not just the sum of each row's `amount`, but the sum of each row's `amount` *times* its corresponding `quantity`. The question did not mention this requirement, but it seems like it would be the desired result.

Furthermore, to recalculate the totals on any change to an input, simply call this function in an event listener for `change` and `keyup` events:

```
$('#dynamicAddRemove')
  .on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    updateTotals();
  })
  .on('change, keyup', 'input', function () {
    updateTotals();
  });
```

Note that we need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here. Assigning a listener to `.quantity` elements on page load will not listen to the `.quantity` elements that are added *after* page load, when the `[name="add"]` button is clicked.

I have an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kduosL90/) for reference.